# Datediff in the select clause only returns the first row

Tags: mysql, datediff

For a table like this named `Activity`:

| player_id | device_id | event_date | games_played |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2016-03-01 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 2016-03-02 | 6 |
| 2 | 3 | 2017-06-25 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2016-02-02 | 0 |
| 3 | 4 | 2018-07-03 | 5 |

I wonder why the following query only returns the result on the first row:

```
select player_id, datediff(event_date, min(event_date)) as date_diff
from Activity
```

Returns:

| player_id | date_diff |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 28 |

I was expecting the fourth row will be returned as it has the minimum `event_date`, something like

| player_id | date_diff |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 |

Comment: Are you passing the player_id as well with Select clause?

Comment: 'Without GROUP BY, there is a single group and it is nondeterministic which...' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have 3 separate `select` query, one to find the min event date in the entire table, one to add the result as a column in the query result, final one to calculate the date difference

```
select player_id, datediff(event_date, min_date) as date_diff from (
  select player_id, event_date,  (
    select min(event_date) from Activity) as min_date from Activity) as query;
```

From your sample data, running the query would get:

```
player_id   date_diff
1   28
1   29
2   509
3   0
3   882
```

Answer (score 0):

When I ran the query in your question, I got an error:

> In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'fiddle.ACTIVITY.PLAYER_ID'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

`min` is an [aggregate function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html) and that's why a GROUP BY is required. However that won't give you the result you want.

In order to get difference between EVENT_DATE and minimum EVENT_DATE for each row, you can use a separate SELECT as a [generated column](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-generated-columns/).

```sql
select PLAYER_ID
      ,datediff(EVENT_DATE, (select min(EVENT_DATE) from ACTIVITY)) as date_diff
  from ACTIVITY
```

Above query returned following result (for sample data in your question):

| PLAYER_ID | date_diff |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 28 |
| 1 | 29 |
| 2 | 509 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 882 |

Refer to this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xHBBXoyh)